# Not checking previous parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying just starting out with python and I'm trying to write a basic program that checks if a word is a palindrome. There is a `while` loop within a `while` loop but the program isn't backing out to check if the first loop is still applicable.

```
while n <= half_word_length:
    while word[n] == word[word_length - 1 - n]:
        n += 1
    if word[n] != word[word_length - n]:
        print('This word is not a palindrome.')
    break
else:
    print('This word is a palindrome.')
```

Regardless of if the input word is a palindrome or not the error message is `"list index out of range"`. I thought it was because it wasn't checking outside of the loop but then a non-palindrome shouldn't cause the program to crash.

Apologies if this is hard to understand, tell me and I'll try fix it up a bit :)

Comment: Regardeless of your code, there are some *pythonic ways* for this kind of problem, for instance: `return word == word[::-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no need for the inner `while` loop, the `break` is incorrectly indented and you compare all letters to the first letter (`word[0]`) not the `n`th letter:

```
while n <= half_word_length:
    if word[n] != word[word_length - n - 1]:
        print('This word is not a palindrome.')
        break
    n += 1
else:
    print('This word is a palindrome.')
```

As julienc points out, though, there are many more Pythonic approaches to this. You should at least be using a `for` loop, rather than creating and incrementing your own index in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with Python, you can use negative indexes:

```
mystr = "hello world"
mystr[0] # "h"
mystr[-1] # "d"
mystr[-2] # "r"
```

Do not hesitate to use them!

```
for i in range(0, len(word)):
    if word[i] != s[-1 - i]:
        return False
return True
```

Then, as I said in my previous comment, there are some *pythonic ways* of doing such things. For instance, you can reverse a string in a single instruction:

```
mystr = "hello world"
mystr[::-1] # "dlrow olleh"
```

So, in a single line:

```
is_palyndrom = (mystr == mystr[::-1])
```

Comment: I don't think it works with `reversed`, as this function returns a `reversed` and not a `str` object: `(reversed("abcba") == "abcba") == False` . Nevertheless, I agree it would be clearer :)

Comment: Oh, good point.. would have to do `mystr == ''.join(reversed(mystr))` which is a bit clunky